# Hash is not Full in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, responsive-design

I have a gallery in Jquery Elastislide.

```
 var imageIndex = 0; 
if (window.location.hash) {
    var imageIndexStr = window.location.hash.replace('#',''); // remove #
    imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexStr, 0); // convert to int
}
```

Thanks to the code above, The gallery got pictures with corresponding Hash.
**www.example.com/gallery.html#1_TITLE_OF_THE_PICTURE**

When I put the code to navigate with arrows of the gallery, I get in the following URL :
**www.example.com/gallery.html#1**

```
_navigate       = function( dir ) {



                // navigate through the large images

                if( anim ) return false;
                anim    = true;

                if( dir === 'right' ) {
                    if( current + 1 >= itemsCount )
                        current = 0;
                    else
                        ++current;
                }
                else if( dir === 'left' ) {
                    if( current - 1 < 0 )
                        current = itemsCount - 1;
                    else
                        --current;
                }

                _showImage( $items.eq( window.location.hash = current) );
```

So, I want some help in order to get in the URL the full Hash.

**www.example.com/gallery.html#1_TITLE_OF_THE_PICTURE**

HTML Code :

```
<head>
<style>
                .es-carousel ul{
                    display:block;
                }
            </style>

            <script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
            <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
                {{if itemsCount > 1}}
                    <div class="rg-image-nav">
                        <a href="#"  class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
                        <a href="#"  class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
                <div class="rg-image"></div>
                <div class="rg-loading"></div>
                <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container_gallery">


<div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">
                        <!-- Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->

                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                                <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                                <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="es-carousel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a href="#0_Title_1"><img src="picture_thumb.jpg" data-large="picture.jpg" alt="Title_1" data-description="Title_1"  /></a></li>

href="#0_Title_2"><img src="picture2_thumb.jpg" data-large="picture2.jpg" alt="Title_2" data-description="Title_2"  /></a></li>

href="#0_Title_3"><img src="picture3_thumb.jpg" data-large="picture3.jpg" alt="Title_3" data-description="Title_3"  /></a></li>



</ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer -->
                    </div><!-- rg-thumbs -->
                </div><!-- rg-gallery -->



</div>
```

Event Navigation :

```
$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).prependTo( $rgGallery );

            if( itemsCount > 1) {
                // addNavigation
                var $navPrev        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-prev'),
                    $navNext        = $rgGallery.find('a.rg-image-nav-next'),
                    $imgWrapper     = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image');

                $navPrev.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    _navigate( 'left' );
                    return false;
                }); 

                $navNext.on('click.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    _navigate( 'right' );
                    return false;
                });

                // add touchwipe events on the large image wrapper
                $imgWrapper.touchwipe({
                    wipeLeft            : function() {
                        _navigate( 'right' );
                    },
                    wipeRight           : function() {
                        _navigate( 'left' );
                    },
                    preventDefaultEvents: false
                });

                $(document).on('keyup.rgGallery', function( event ) {
                    if (event.keyCode == 39)
                        _navigate( 'right' );
                    else if (event.keyCode == 37)
                        _navigate( 'left' );    
                });

            }

        },
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you can add a bind method to the document hash.  so whenever the hash changes it will call the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is setting the hash value to just be a number which would cause it to become something like: `www.example.com/gallery.html#1`.

```
_showImage( $items.eq( window.location.hash = current) );
```

It looks to me like your navigate function is not putting the title onto the new hash value when you change pictures.  I think you want something like this:

```
window.location.hash = current + "_" + newPictureTitle;
_showImage( $items.eq(current) );
```

Where you obviously need to fill in the value of newPictureTitle

---

Based on the HTML and other javascript you've shown, your `_navigate()` function could work like this:

```
_navigate  = function( dir ) {
    // navigate through the large images
    if( anim ) return false;
    anim    = true;

    if( dir === 'right' ) {
        if( ++current >= itemsCount )
            current = 0;
    } else if( dir === 'left' ) {
        if( --current < 0 )
            current = itemsCount - 1;
    }

    // show the right image
    _showImage( $items.eq(current) );

    // now get the right image title so it can go in the hash value
    // we assume here that current is a zero based index
    var links = $("#rg-gallery .es-carousel li a");
    // use getAttribute here to get the raw href that's in the 
    // HTML source file (not a fully qualified URL)
    window.location.hash = links.get(current).getAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how can I have the full Hash ? I have got this code that let appear the full Hash when I click on the thumb of a picture. `var imageIndex = 0; 
if (window.location.hash) {
    var imageIndexStr = window.location.hash.replace('#',''); // remove #
    imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexStr, 0); // convert to int
}`

Comment: It doesn't work... In HTML code, I have for example `<a href="#3_Title"><img src=....></a>` where href is the Hash. So I think something is missing after the current `window.location.hash = current + ......... `

Comment: @JasonB. - You'll have to show me your HTML (put it in your question, not in a comment) and explain how the navigation event is started.

Comment: Hope I put what you need to understand.

Comment: @JasonB. - OK I added a new version of `_navigate()` to my answer based on the HTML you provided.  It looks in the HTML to find the clickable links that correspond to each image and uses current to find the targeted one.  It then gets that href and sets the `location.hash ` to that.

Comment: @JasonB. - if it's a clarification about my answer, you can post a comment to ask for that clarification.  If it's a new question, you should post a new question.  StackOverflow is meant to be question/answer/done, not ongoing discussion about a development project.

Comment: Ok, I think I will post a question so. It's about Google Analytics and this code. Thanks.

Comment: Here the question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538115/google-analytics-and-hash-anchor-doesnt-work [link], the fact is that I can't find a solution with the code that you gave me because it's about arrows in the naviguation of the gallery .. That's why I look back to you, wondering if you have any idea to put a Google Analytics code into the code you gave me in order to get the stats from hash/anchor... Thanks for your comprehension.