# Google Analytics and hash/anchor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hash, google-analytics, statistics, anchor

I hope you can help me.

I have a gallery in Javascript.
Each picture has a specific hash.

**www.example.com/gallery.html#title_1**

My stats are on Google Analytics but hash doesn't exist even when I tried this in the respective code :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash]);
```

or this :

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
```

Any idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_setAllowAnchor` is for a completely different use case.

The right way to do it is as you said:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash]);
```

But you need to execute this after the hash has changed. I think you are executing this when the page loads. When the hash changes the page doesn't reload so you need to run this function call explicitly again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried with this code, but it doesn't work, that's why I put a question about this problem.

Comment: Read my answer again. You need to execute this code after you change the hash, not on the page load.

Comment: After many manipulation, I found the answer. I had to put this line of code on my javascript code in order to get the right stats. I don't know if your answer helps me, certainly. The problem is solved now. Thanks.